# order by in rownumber is used while returning the row for select or not.

Tags: sql-server

Does Following query needs  order by clause or not? because i have seen in normal select one has to put order by else result is not granted for inserted order.

```
 SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ) AS Row#,
      name, recovery_model_desc
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE database_id < 5
    order by name
```

yours sincerly

Comment: We should always add ORDER BY clause if we require sorted output. No guarantee that output will be sorted or not.

Comment: What do you mean by inserted order? A relational database table is an unordered set of rows by definition so the only way to guarantee order is with the outermost `ORDER BY` as you have done. See http://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/